# Shortest path between 2 points passing through a point of a convex polygon's border.

Tags: computer-science, computational-geometry

This Problem was in a local programming contest that my school made. the problem says:
***Given 2 points:***
***$(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ (inside the polygon of course)***
***and a number $n$ and $n$ points which make up the convex polygon***
***what is the shortest path that joins these two points with the added constraint of having to go to the border of the given convex polygon?***

***Input and Output:***
**$3 \le$ $n$ $\le 5 \cdot 10^4$**
**$-10^9 \le x_i,y_i \le 10^9$**
**No 3 points are colinear**
**Print the length of the shortest path that satisfies the above constraints**

***NOTE:***
I couldn't solve the problem because I thought something was missing.. so please correct me if I was wrong.
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Are you familiar with the "milkmaid problem" where the milkmaid has to go to the river to get water for the cow?

Comment: Also, as it's a programming contest, you should clarify what the inputs / outputs are. IE Is the polygon part of the input? Like you mentioned, if you don't know the polygon at all, then this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @CalvinLin No, I am still a beginner.

Comment: @CalvinLin No again, the polygon is not in the input

Comment: wait.. I just discovered that they give me the $n$ points that make up the polygon :/

Comment: Try the problem for "given 2 points, and 1 line segment, find the shortest path that touches the line segment". State what you've tried and where you're stuck. Once you can do this, the general problem is just $n$ times.

Comment: @CalvinLin and just compare the results for the $n$ segments the polygon is made up of?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116479/discussion-between-cookiebuster-and-calvin-lin).